# how to show each two <p> in one line inside a div

Tags: html, css

i have a loop inside a jsp page , for each element of my arrayList i print a

pragraph, this my code  :

```
<% for(object ob:myList){ %>
<p> <%=ob.getName()%></p>
<%}%>
```

this code show me a lot of paragraphs, but each paragraph in one row, my issue is : how to show each two paragraphs in one line

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to have two paragraph tags in 1 line you need some css:

```
p { 
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
}
```

or

```
p { 
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

The 50% width is for 2 `<p>`'s to be on the same row and take half of the width.

Hope that helps.

.

**Update**

https://jsfiddle.net/v6sjq5jj/1/

.

**Second update**

Or use **table-row** and **table-cell**, which is the best-solution in my opinion and it is for multiple p tags.
https://jsfiddle.net/v6sjq5jj/2/

Comment: Hi @Valentin Vrinceanu , thank you it works fine for me , (y)

Comment: @Ali In your case you can't use `display: table-row / table-cell` as it will give all `p` in one row, not 2-by-2

Answer (score 2):

Also other way if you have the *p* tag inner a div, section etc. You can use property flex for display:

```
.div{
    display: flex;
}
```

Update: https://jsfiddle.net/hectoruch/fk7gcza7/

Answer (score 1):

For all modern browsers, use `display: flex`

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
div p {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;    /*  make the border width be included in width  */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>First</p>
  <p>Second</p>
  <p>Third</p>
  <p>Fourth</p>
  <p>Fifth</p>
</div>
```